# Include iCloud on save dialog box in mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, icloud, nsdocument

I have implemented the `iCloud` support on my Mac document-based app. 
`NSDocument` subclass can handle open e save file on local storage and `iCloud`.
But, I can upload my files on `iCloud` only dragging it on the Open-New File Panel.
When the app prompt the user the location to save the file, `iCloud` is not on the list.
Isn't it supported by default like in TextEdit? I have to implement with my own code?

Image here:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi have implemented a method to show a custom save dialog and it shows also iCloud options. But it works only one time to save. second time i call the app doesn't work.

Comment: the code is here: http://pastebin.com/1PFeSypR

Comment: I've got the same problem. I'm trying to enable iCloud document storage in my NSDocument-based OS X app. There is no 'iCloud' option when the save panel is running. The following works fine: 1)
NSOpenPanel has both an iCloud and file system tab.
2) The document popup menu has a 'Move to iCloud…' option.
3) Saving a document that is stored in iCloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by

1. recreating certificates and provisioning profiles
2. removing the LSItemContentTypes key for my CFBundleDocumentTypes entry in the
   Info.plist. I also removed the UTExportedTypeDeclarations entry (which may or may not have contained errors).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. but it is solved when I fix code sign problem. 
this problem invoked by code sign wrong.