# Open Dialog with "iCloud" and "On my mac"?

Tags: cocoa, icloud

How do you create the Open Dialog with the choice between "iCloud" and "On my mac" in Cocoa? Using the `-[NSDocumentController beginOpenPanelWithCompletionHandler:]` does not offer the choice between "iCloud" and "On my mac". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try see if this question helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212337/include-icloud-on-save-dialog-box-in-mac-app

Comment: Sadly, no. I'm looking for this dialog: http://www.macobserver.com/imgs/landau/2012/ML_1-iCloud_dialog.jpg

Comment: Can you save files to iCloud though, so are you only missing the open dialog with iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already done this but you need the iCloud entitlements set in Xcode for iCloud integration.