# OS X: open panel does not show icloud documents

Tags: macos, icloud, nsdocumentcontroller

I have an app where I want to open panel and user can select a document from local storage or from icloud. I have icloud enabled and also files and data but open panel shows only local storage data. I tried with these functions:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] runModalOpenPanel:openPanel forTypes:supportedDocumentTypes];
```

or

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] beginOpenPanelWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *array) {

}];
```

or

```
NSInteger result = [openPanel runModal];
```

Did I forget about something or did I make it wrong?
Is it at all possible from non document-based app?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the iCloud entitlements and the ubiquity container ID correctly ?  And you have installed a development profile with the iCloud entitlements?

Comment: The open panel should automatically provide an iCloud button or link

Comment: Yes, I checked. I set iCloud entitlements and uibiquity container ID is set to my team identifier and bundle id.

Comment: I just noticed you are using a non-document based app - you're out of luck then but the container is still available programatically.

Comment: So I have to list all available icloud documents myself?

Comment: It would seem so, but if you have documents in iCloud maybe you should consider using a document based app?

Comment: Also try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212337/include-icloud-on-save-dialog-box-in-mac-app?rq=1

Comment: Ok, I did it myself, because I only want to select some documents from the iCloud, e.g. pdf and the app does not edit this file. Please post your comment as an answer then I can accept it.